# I am not able to access plugin portal of netbeans site

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am not able to download any netbeans IDE plugins. When I am trying to access the plugin tab of netbeans site from any browser,there also not able to access it...
  Is it that site is down or having some problem at myend...

Answer (score 0):

The plugin center is down for maintanance:
https://twitter.com/netbeans/status/736521347866759168